# How to send binary message from python stomp to ActiveMQ

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, stomp

I am trying Python `stomp` client to send a binary message to JVM via ActiveMQ and I need it as JMS `BytesMessage`, but it comes as `TextMessage`.

I would imagine it should be possible, as I can do the opposite (JVM to Python), but not sure how.

Anyone knows the trick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the `content-length` header on the STOMP message you send in order for it to be translated into a JMS `BytesMessage`. See the "Working with JMS Text/Bytes Messages and Stomp" section of the [ActiveMQ STOMP documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html).

Answer (score 1):

stomp.Connection.send() always specifies **content-length header**.
You need to add stomp.Connection(**auto_content_length=False**),
Because the default is stomp.Connection(auto_content_length=True) which specifies the content-length header only for bytes messages and not for string messages.

Comment: In fact, this answer helped me achieve the opposite (send text message and not bytemessage) - thanks!

Comment: It seems the default value is not overridable when using the `stomp.py` command line  on Ubuntu. I will use the API instead.